# How to Oracle GoldenGate Microservices Architecture with kafka handler

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

I want to use OGG Microservices Architecture and extract the data into Kafka. All I found in google is about ogg classic, not micro services.

I am new for ogg, so if there is some detailed artical will be very great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for writing directly to Kafka from OGG Microservices Architecture version 19.1 and earlier.  For that, you would use Oracle GoldenGate for Big Data.

Comment: What you're saying is basically taking care of extraction with OGG MA and use an OGG for Big Data extract process (with kafka handler)?